# Flutter how do scroll controllers work,how do they get executed

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

Flutter : i am new to flutter , i wanted to know how do they work behind the scenes(what actually happens when we attach a scroll controller to  a scrollable widget.) . i read the docs but its hard for me to understand.

````
                  controller: ** _controller **,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Wrap(
                    // direction: Axis.horizontal,
                    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                    spacing: 4.0,
                    runSpacing: 4.0,
                    children: *MY WIDGET*,
                  ),```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question and something I was curious about as well. If you're using `ListView`, it subclasses another class called `BoxScrollView` which itself subclasses `ScrollView` and it's in fact `ScrollView` that holds onto the `ScrollController` instance if you look at this code:

```dart
  /// {@template flutter.widgets.scroll_view.controller}
  /// An object that can be used to control the position to which this scroll
  /// view is scrolled.
  ///
  /// Must be null if [primary] is true.
  ///
  /// A [ScrollController] serves several purposes. It can be used to control
  /// the initial scroll position (see [ScrollController.initialScrollOffset]).
  /// It can be used to control whether the scroll view should automatically
  /// save and restore its scroll position in the [PageStorage] (see
  /// [ScrollController.keepScrollOffset]). It can be used to read the current
  /// scroll position (see [ScrollController.offset]), or change it (see
  /// [ScrollController.animateTo]).
  /// {@endtemplate}
  final ScrollController? controller;
```

If you then look in the `build()` function of `ScrollView` you'll see this gem:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> slivers = buildSlivers(context);
    final AxisDirection axisDirection = getDirection(context);

    final ScrollController? scrollController =
        primary ? PrimaryScrollController.of(context) : controller;
    final Scrollable scrollable = Scrollable(
      dragStartBehavior: dragStartBehavior,
      axisDirection: axisDirection,
      controller: scrollController,
```

You see the `Scrollable` instance which takes the `controller` in as a parameter?

I'm not going to paste more code since it can get quite long but I suggest that you go ahead and look at the source code for `Scrollablle` and also `ScrollView` to get a better understanding of how they work.